# reveal text from center against a background image

Tags: css, background-image, css-animations

I'm trying to reveal text from the center against an element that has a background image. If I make the background of the animation a solid color, then that solid color appears around the text until the animation is done. If I put the same background image behind the text as is the behind the containing element, then a different version of that same image appears around my text. Any suggestions?

html:

```
<div class="container-big" id="the-wall">
      <div class="chapter-hed">
        <h5>PART 1</h5>
        <h4 class="showhead">My heading</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#the-wall {
  background-image: url(../img/wopo-3.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: black;
}
.chapter-hed h4 {
  font-family: 'proxima-nova';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 5rem;
  letter-spacing: -2.4px;
  line-height: 6.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #e40d0d;
}

.chapter-hed h4:before {
left:0;
}
.chapter-hed h4:after {
right:0;
}
.chapter-hed h4:after,.chapter-hed h4:before { 
position:absolute;
content:"";
height:100%;
height: 109px;
/*background:black;*/
background-image: url(../img/wopo-3.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: black;

}
.showhead:after, .showhead:before {
    animation: revealText 4s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards; 
}

@keyframes revealText {
  0% {
     width:50%
    }
  100% {
     width:0%
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added 2 wrappers for your class. One slides to the left, the other to the right. The net effect is that the element keeps centered, and is revealed progressively

```css
#the-wall {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: black;
}

.showheadctn1,
.showheadctn2 {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.showheadctn1 {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

.showheadctn2 {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.showhead {
  font-family: 'proxima-nova';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 5rem;
  letter-spacing: -2.4px;
  line-height: 6.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #e40d0d;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

.showheadctn1,
.showheadctn2,
.showhead {
  animation: revealText 4s infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes revealText {
  0% {}
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-big" id="the-wall">
  <div class="chapter-hed">
    <h5>PART 1</h5>
    <div class="showheadctn1">
      <div class="showheadctn2">
        <h4 class="showhead">My heading</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make 3 layers.
The bottom of the image you want.
In between the text.
The front again the image, but this time split in half.

And you do the same animation you have now but backwards. (On the third layer, logically)

Sure there is a more appropriate solution, but it is the first thing that has happened to me in my head